# Finding a Lyapunov function to say whether $\ddot{x}+g(x)=0$ is stable at the origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The given function is $\ddot{x}+g(x)=0$ and $g(x)$ is a scalar function. Formulating the properties of $g(x)$ to say the origin is (asymptotically) stable or unstable.

First I choose a Lyapunov function $V(x)=\int g(x)\,dx+\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2$, and by some computation, $\dot{V}(x)=0$. The only problem is that I need $V(x)>0$. Therefore, define $U$ be the neighborhood containing $0$, if $\int g(x)\,dx>0$ for $x\in U\setminus\{0\}$, then $V(x)>0$, the origin is stable.

The problem is, if I cannot find any neighborhood containing the origin with the property $\int g(x)\,dx>0$, then the $V(x)$ I defined is not available. I can't tell the other condition for different $g(x)$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Add any constant to your V.

Comment: Just a side note: the more important is that Lyapunov function has a local minimum at the equilibrium which stability you want to study. Conditions $V(0) = 0$ and $V(x) > 0$ for $x \neq 0$ encodes just that. So this is why @Artem comment always can fix $V(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you need $g(0)=0$ to have any stationary point at all. After that you see that with $V$ as defined and the integration constant chosen so that $V(0,0)=0$ you get in approximation
$$
V(x,p)=\frac12p^2+\frac12 g'(0) x^2+O(x^3).
$$
Thus if $g'(0)$ is positive, there is some small neighborhood where the quadratic terms dominate and thus $V$ is positive.

A more general condition is that you need a sign change of $g$ in $x=0$ from negative to positive to get a positive $V$.